OpenTelemetry Collector Prometheus exporter fails with "was collected before with the same name and label values"
I have a java service deployed in k8s with a opentelemetry collector attached as sidecar to export the metrics from the application.
I have configured prometheus to scrape the pod via a ServiceMonitor in the same namespace.
My otel collector config looks like this:
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          http:
          grpc:

    processors:
      batch:
        timeout: 5s
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_percentage: 80
        spike_limit_percentage: 20

    extensions:
      zpages: {}
      memory_ballast:
        # Memory Ballast size should be max 1/3 to 1/2 of memory.
        size_mib: 256

    exporters:
      debug:
        verbosity: detailed
      zipkin:
        endpoint: "http://jaeger-collector.observability.svc.cluster.local:9411/api/v2/spans"
        tls:
          insecure: true
      otlp:
        endpoint: "jaeger-collector.observability.svc.cluster.local:4317"
        tls:
          insecure: true
        sending_queue:
          num_consumers: 4
          queue_size: 100
        retry_on_failure:
          enabled: true
      prometheus:
        endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
        add_metric_suffixes: false

    service:
      extensions: [zpages, memory_ballast]
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [otlp]
        metrics:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [prometheus]

All seems to be good , but when I look in the logs I see the following error.
"metric XXX was collected before with the same name and label values"
2024-05-30T14:42:12.390Z    error   prometheusexporter@v0.96.0/log.go:23    error gathering metrics: collected metric "http_client_duration" { label:{name:"container_id"  value:"9fc9d223e2e87e1ac60e3c02fe8430f865fbb479adb0f8540cbd1aafaf5fd721"}  label:{name:"host_arch"  value:"amd64"}  label:{name:"host_name"  value:"events-collector-57b85cc576-vh7br"}  label:{name:"http_method"  value:"GET"}  label:{name:"http_status_code"  value:"200"}  label:{name:"job"  value:"events-collector"}  label:{name:"k8s_container_name"  value:"events-collector"}  label:{name:"k8s_deployment_name"  value:"events-collector"}  label:{name:"k8s_namespace_name"  value:"platform"}  label:{name:"k8s_node_name"  value:"aks-aerasvc3-35271952-vmss000004"}  label:{name:"k8s_pod_name"  value:"events-collector-57b85cc576-vh7br"}  label:{name:"k8s_replicaset_name"  value:"events-collector-57b85cc576"}  label:{name:"net_peer_name"  value:"config-server-svc.central-services"}  label:{name:"net_protocol_name"  value:"http"}  label:{name:"net_protocol_version"  value:"1.1"}  label:{name:"os_description"  value:"Linux 5.15.0-1051-azure"}  label:{name:"os_type"  value:"linux"}  label:{name:"service_name"  value:"events-collector"}  label:{name:"service_version"  value:"2.6.0-main-b141"}  label:{name:"telemetry_auto_version"  value:"1.32.1"}  label:{name:"telemetry_sdk_language"  value:"java"}  label:{name:"telemetry_sdk_name"  value:"opentelemetry"}  label:{name:"telemetry_sdk_version"  value:"1.34.1"}  histogram:{sample_count:1  sample_sum:117.409334  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:0}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:5}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:10}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:25}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:50}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:75}  bucket:{cumulative_count:0  upper_bound:100}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:250}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:500}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:750}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:1000}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:2500}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:5000}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:7500}  bucket:{cumulative_count:1  upper_bound:10000}}} was collected before with the same name and label values
    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "prometheus"}
github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/prometheusexporter.(*promLogger).Println
    github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/exporter/prometheusexporter@v0.96.0/log.go:23
github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp.HandlerForTransactional.func1
    github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.19.0/prometheus/promhttp/http.go:144
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP
    net/http/server.go:2136
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP
    net/http/server.go:2514
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/config/confighttp.(*decompressor).ServeHTTP
    go.opentelemetry.io/collector/config/confighttp@v0.96.0/compression.go:160
go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.(*middleware).serveHTTP
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@v0.49.0/handler.go:225
go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp.NewMiddleware.func1.1
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@v0.49.0/handler.go:83
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP
    net/http/server.go:2136
go.opentelemetry.io/collector/config/confighttp.(*clientInfoHandler).ServeHTTP
    go.opentelemetry.io/collector/config/confighttp@v0.96.0/clientinfohandler.go:26
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP
    net/http/server.go:2938
net/http.(*conn).serve
    net/http/server.go:2009

I tried almost everything but nothing seems to fix it. From the error it seems that I have an exact same metrics that was collected before and because of that its failing do collect it again.
Any idea where I can look ? maybe at prometheus side somewhere ? Or is there a way I can instruct Prometheus to ignore this duplicate and just go fwd with the scrape ?
Thanks for the help
Mircea

How does your otel config looks like?

@ArpitAgarwal updated the description. Nothing impressive , just a basic one.

So, your application is writing to otel in otlp protocol. Can you confirm if the timestamp is always increasing? Paste some snippet of that code also.

Yes , I can confirm that the timestamp is always increasing. @ArpitAgarwal
